# GitHub API v3: Which base_tree SHA values are accepted when writing a tree

Tags: git, version-control, github, github-api

When [reading a tree using the github api](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/):

```
GET /repos/:user/:repo/git/trees/:sha
```

you can either pass

1. The SHA of a commit, in which case it seems to automatically resolve to the tree in the commit, and might save you a round trip to fetch the tree SHA from the commit.
2. Or simply pass the tree's SHA

I was wondering if you can also pass the commit's SHA for `base_tree` when calling the "Create a Tree" api?

```
POST /repos/:user/:repo/git/trees
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to work without a problem.

The way I tested it was:

1. GET the commit sha from "refs/heads/master" (returns `old_commit_sha`)
2. POST a new tree with `old_commit_sha` as the base_tree and a new or updated file (returns `new_tree_sha`)
3. POST a new commit with the `new_tree_sha` as the tree and `old_commit_sha` as the parent (returns `new_commit_sha`)
4. POST a new "refs/heads/master" (set it to `new_commit_sha`)

I then verified that everything looked correct on github itself... and it did.

This only saves one step in adding or updating a file in a repository, but might be useful for someone.

Comment: Oh.. You got me... What is the best way to update multiple level ?